# How does Google Analytics determine mobile device with EasyTracker Windows SDK

Tags: c#, google-analytics, uwp, app.xaml

I Have a UWP App and I'm using googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com.
I set

```
GAServiceManager.Current.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Touch; Arm; NOKIA; RM-1045_1116)";
```

Then I have:

```
EasyTracker.GetTracker().SetStartSession(session);
```

And:

```
EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendView(screenName);
```

But Google Analytics always says the device is a Nokia Lumia 435.
Where does Google gets this information?